Generating a whitening filter using MATLAB cceps() function
I have a few thousand realisations of a discrete stochastic process. I am trying to generate a whitening filter from these realisations. I am expected to use the MATLAB cceps() function to generate the whitening filter.
The book that I have access to, states that the cepstrum is generated using the autocorrelation of the input signal. After which I am lost, I have no idea how to generate the filter coefficients from the cepstrum sequence. I also don't understand how to connect the filter coefficients (if I can even find them) to build a filter. Are these coefficients the filter coefficients of a FIR filter or IIR filter?
My initial thought process was that I would determine the filter coefficients for each signal, meaning I would have several thousand whitening filters.
This may seem like a stupid question, showing my lack of understanding of the underlying concepts, but I'd appreciate any help or advice.
Thank you!
